# How to support HEIC/HEIF images in go backend?

Tags: go, mime-types, heic

I am pretty new to Go. I have some image upload code and I am trying to upload a `*.heic` image that is produced by iPhones. My code is doing the following:

```
contentType := http.DetectContentType(fileBytes)
```

`DetectContentType` does not know how to detect content type for `HEIC`, which results in default `application/octet-stream` content type. Is there a way to add support for new content types that Go does not know how to handle yet?

Answer (score 1):

The `http.DetectContentType` function is designed to match the [Media Type Sniffing](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-abarth-mime-sniff) specification.  As such, it's not extensible.

However, you don't need to extend it: there's nothing preventing you from writing your own function that detects HEIC, and that falls back to `http.DetectContentType` if the data does not match HEIC.